# error: resource style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat (aka com.example.reza.reza:style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat) not found

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

when my android studio's sdk version is set on 28, in bulding gradle i get this error "error: resource style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat (aka com.example.reza.reza:style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat) not found."
then i decrease to 27 and it run without any problem.
thanks for your answers .

Comment: please write your style.xml file here

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried (=your code). Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: there is not any cod. this problem for building gradle. i run same code in two winow. one of them with sdkversion 27 and one of them with sdkversion 28 and that window that has sdkversion 28 not build and get error.